# there are cache in an app with angular6 and nodejs?

Tags: ios, iphone, angular, sass, angular6

I am modifying an app that I have not done. I am very new in angular.

I have made some modifications to the scss file which is the one that gives style to the page. I see the changes applied but the client does not. I have tried it on chrome from android, on chrome from MAC and on safari from MAC and it works perfectly for me.

The scss file is set like this:

```
@Component ({
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
   selector: 'home',
   styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
   templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
```

I understand that the `ViewEncapsulation.None` makes the scss code look in the head with the  tag

That's why I don't understand if it's a cache problem ... I take the `ViewEncapsulation.None` off and put a version on it?

It would be like this?
`styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss?v=1.1']?`

Comment: Normally, there is no need to do that as the name of the generated css file during the build process already changes ith every build, which avoids cache problems

Comment: And why can't he see the changes applied?

Comment: is this deployed to PROD? any CDN used for this? did you try using Ctrl+F5 for this?

Comment: I can not explain to all customers who have ever entered the website that make ctrl + F5